# Can i access a superior class?

Tags: java

Sorry for my bad english.

Hello i wondering me if i can acces to a parent from it's children. for exemple with a "A" object wherein I create a "B" . It's possible, does this method has disadvantages ? if so what are the solutions?

edit 1: in my case i have a main object which instantiate two objects, a object which handle a database and an other which create view but i want to erase view from database so can i put the main object in the constructor of the view creator class and use the main object function in oder to access to the database and erase the view ? or it is a practice to avoid ?

edit2: sorry for the error, i'm talking about object, not about classes

edit 3: here is an example made by @DaveHowes (thanks to him)

```
class A {

public void doSomething(){
 B b = new B(this);
}

public void doSomethingElse(){
   // Do something wondrous
}

}

Class B {

private A par = null;
public B(A parent){
  par = parent;
}

public void callMethodInParent(){
   par.doSomethingElse();
}
  }
```

P.S: I'm not talking about inheritance.

Comment: Look into inheritance.

Comment: look for inheritance and (for java also look into access specifiers )

Comment: You can always access non-static members from outside class scope provided you have an object and the members are public.

Comment: You can do super.<methodName>

Comment: I believe you are referring to nested classes and here is an [example from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105955/c-sharp-nested-class-access-parent-member) and an [example from java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201/how-do-you-get-a-reference-to-the-enclosing-class-from-an-anonymous-inner-class)

Comment: With no pseudo-code, example, or otherwise anything that can explain what you're talking about, it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: OP is **not talking** about inheritance.

Comment: First, what are you trying to do? Second, did you want to do that in Java, C++ or C? Can you post a self contained example in whatever programming language you're actually trying to do this in?

Comment: it's a general question concerning java,c and c++ programing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but here goes .....

If you mean that in Class A, you instantiate an instance of Class B, then Class B will **not** have access to the data and methods of Class A **unless** you pass a reference to an instance of Class A into Class B. This is often done in the constructor of Class B

This contrived example illustrates what I mean

```
class A {

    public void doSomething(){
     B b = new B(this);
    }

    public void doSomethingElse(){
       // Do something wondrous
    }

}

Class B {

   private A par = null;
   public B(A parent){
      par = parent;
   }

   public void callMethodInParent(){
       par.doSomethingElse();
   }
}
```

Comment: yes, i'm talking about that, ok thanks, so it's not a deprecated method ?

Comment: If you mean is it bad practice? then I'd say "No" - in my experience it's quite a common thing to do. If you have a lot of objects and you find yourself glueing them together like this though, then it might be time to rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to nested/inner classes and here is an [example from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105955/c-sharp-nested-class-access-parent-member) and an [example from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201/how-do-you-get-a-reference-to-the-enclosing-class-from-an-anonymous-inner-class)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be talking about inner classes.  Such that

```
public class Outer {

    private class Inner {

    }
}
```

In this case, the inner class can see all members of it's parent, and vice versa.

```
public class Outer {

    private String id = "123c";

        private class Inner {

        public void useID() {
            String newID = id; //this works
        }
    }
```

An inner class is meant to be an extension of it's outer class.  When a task contains a sub-task great enough for it's own object, but is still very tightly tied the main object, it can be put into an inner class which helps add a layer of separation.  Since an inner class is an extensions of it's outer class, they rely on being able to see each other's members regardless of visibility.